# mlogit. Negative value for sd

Tags: r, mlogit

I fit a mixed logit using `mlogit` package, but I get negative values for standard deviation. Any idea why I am getting negative values and how this is interpreted?

```
library(mlogit)
#data
code=c( "obs4694", "obs4681", "obs1362", "obs3372", "obs1001", "obs747",  "obs4738", "obs3861", "obs3044", "obs2651",
         "obs2354", "obs1805", "obs3289", "obs2460", "obs1547", "obs2904", "obs534", "obs2818", "obs3681", "obs2516",
         "obs2527", "obs2283", "obs2173", "obs3765", "obs444",  "obs4513", "obs1005", "obs1934", "obs3229", "obs2561")
mcollege=c("no",  "no",  "no",  "yes", "yes", "no",  "yes", "no",  "no",  "no",
           "no",  "no",  "no",  "no",  "no",  "yes", "no",  "yes", "no",  "yes",
           "yes", "no",  "no",  "no",  "no",  "no",  "no",  "no",  "no", "no")
Dist=c(1,1,4,1,4,3,2,4,1,3,3,4,1,3,3,2,1,2,1,1,3,2,4,1,3,3,4,1,3,1)
Data <- data.frame(code, mcollege, Dist)

# model
MNLData <- mlogit.data(Data, id='code', shape='wide', choice='Dist')
Output <- mlogit(Dist~1|mcollege|1, MNLData,rpar=c('2:(intercept)'='n', '3:(intercept)'='n', '4:(intercept)'='n', '2:mcollegeyes'='n', '3:mcollegeyes'='n', '4:mcollegeyes'='n'), R=100, halton=NA, print.level=1)
summary(Output)
```

When I check the coefficient results in summary the estimated sd for four of the variables are negative:

```
Coefficients :
                   Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)
2:(intercept)       -2.6593    56.1853 -0.0473   0.9622
3:(intercept)      -14.4052   389.3052 -0.0370   0.9705
4:(intercept)      -12.3455   323.4815 -0.0382   0.9696
2:mcollegeyes      -21.7190  1322.7599 -0.0164   0.9869
3:mcollegeyes      -32.4405   894.8809 -0.0363   0.9711
4:mcollegeyes      -68.2683  7951.4086 -0.0086   0.9931
sd.2:(intercept)    -1.1784    73.3574 -0.0161   0.9872   #negative
sd.3:(intercept)    52.0240  1373.2141  0.0379   0.9698
sd.4:(intercept)    27.0898   698.0700  0.0388   0.9690
sd.2:mcollegeyes  -275.3367 14154.1320 -0.0195   0.9845   #negative
sd.3:mcollegeyes   -41.2779  1680.3746 -0.0246   0.9804   #negative
sd.4:mcollegeyes   -96.8595  7558.5953 -0.0128   0.9898   #negative
```

Comment: Where do you see the standard deviation?

Comment: @Pascal: I updated the post

Comment: At least, `stdev(Output)` are positive.

Comment: Interesting. does it mean that I can rely on `stdev(Output)` and assume that estimated SDs are all positive?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I posted similar question on Cross Validated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interpret the values as positive. The negative values are a side-effect of how the MSLE algorithm works (specifically how the normal variates are generated; since the normal distribution symmetric, it doesn't matter if you generate a $N(\mu,\sigma)$-distributed random variable with $\mu + \sigma Z$ or $\mu - \sigma Z$ where $Z$ is a standard normal; furthermore, allowing $\sigma$ to be negative means that the optimization is unconstrained rather than constrained, making it a much easier problem to solve).

For publication/distribution to others, I just manually change the negative values to positive values in the table of estimates. If you do manipulation/graphing of the estimates themselves you'll want to make sure you use `abs()` or `stdev()` so you don't get unexpected results. If you look in the source code of `stdev.rpar()` you'll see that it simply applies `abs()` to the `sigma` component of the `rpar` object.